# Android Stuio On BackPressed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to ask the user if they are sure about exiting this activity.....But my AlertDialog shows for a milli second and the activity closes anyways. How can I fix that?

```
public class SearchingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searching);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `super.onBackPressed()`, so the default behavior is still happening. Remove that line if you don't want to run the default behavior of immediately dismissing the activity.